# Define execution order for same script on multiple gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the same scrolling script attached to multiple game objects. But I want them executed in sequence. At present they were executing, I can say randomly so they aren't able to achieve synchronisation with each other in order.

So I want them executed based on each gameobject's order rather then each one randomly selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own `UpdateManually` method and call it in the appropriate order yourself. For example:

```cs
public class ScrollScriptUpdater : MonoBehaviour
{
    // set references according to desired update order
    // this can be done in the editor or via script if appropriate
    public List<ScrollScript> ScrollScripts;

    void Update ()
    {
        // this updates in the natural order of the list,
        // list item 0, 1, 2, ...
        foreach (var script in ScrollScripts)
        {
            script.UpdateManually();
        }
    }
}

public class ScrollScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void UpdateManually()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: No way exist to specify same scripts order in multiple objects ?

Comment: @Siddharth I couldn't think of a way without relying on another script to control execution order manually like this.

Comment: @Siddharth No, there is no way to tell Unity how to deal with the order of execution of objects beyond the order in which they are created *or* by creating a script as Sonny has, and doing it manually.